# Firebase auth remember doesn't work for new tabs

Tags: firebase

I want browser to remember the login until the browser is closed. So, if the user opens a new tab, he/she still remains logged in. I tried with the following two options stated in the doc:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html#section-logging-in

- **default** - It remembers the user even when the browser is closed and reopened.
- **sessionOnly** - It remembers for the current tab only. If the user open the app in a new tab, they are no longer logged in for that tab.

So, you can see we need another intermediary solution where user will still be logged in for the new tabs and that session should be alive until user exit the browser completely. This is the existing behavior that all websites follow for non-remembered login. And for remembered login, they use the **default** option.

That means, firebase is seriously in need of that intermediary option. My questions are:

1. Is Firebase going to have that intermediary remember option?
2. Until this options is implemented, is there a secure workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Cross post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/zkrJsCh0_sw